# Change matrix negative values to absolute values

Tags: python, list

How could I change the negative values into their positive values. I have to write a **procedure** so no return value or print

I have a matrix:

```
  [-5,-8,-8,-7,-8],
  [-4,-2,-4,-8,-9],
  [-4,-2,-5,-8,-7]
```

I want the matrix have positive numbers. So

```
  [5,8,8,7,8],
  [4,2,4,8,9],
  [4,2,5,8,7]
```

I have this:

```
def procedure(matrix):
   map(abs, matrix)
```

But it does not work at all.

Comment: without `abs()`: `[[x * -1 if x < 0 else x for x in y] for y in lst]`

Comment: What do you mean by "a *procedure*"?  Do you mean that the function should mutate its argument? (This is bad practise btw, but if that is what your assignment requires, you have to do it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but `map()` will operate on each row of the matrix as the matrix is a list of lists. Instead you need some kind of loop to apply the `abs()` function to each element in each row. I would suggest a list-comprehension which has the additional advantage of returning a `list` rather than a map object.

```
def procedure(matrix):
    return [[abs(x) for x in row] for row in matrix]
```

Test:

```
>>> m = [
...   [-5,-8,-8,-7,-8],
...   [-4,-2,-4,-8,-9],
...   [-4,-2,-5,-8,-7]
... ]
>>> procedure(m)
[
  [5, 8, 8, 7, 8],
  [4, 2, 4, 8, 9],
  [4, 2, 5, 8, 7]
]
```

Comment: The OP said "no return value"

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Now no return or print

```py
x = [
    [-5, -8, -8, -7, -8],
    [-4, -2, -4, -8, -9],
    [-4, -2, -5, -8, -7],
]  # create matrice (list of lists)


def get_abs(x):
    for line_number in range(len(x)):  # go through lines
        for element_number in range(len(x[line_number])):  # go  through line 
            # get abs
            x[line_number][element_number] = abs(x[line_number][element_number])


get_abs(x)  # get abs

print(x)  # test what we have got
```

Comment: The OP said "no return value"

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica thanks, changed the answer to "no return no print" solution

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) & [numpy.absolute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)

```
a = [[-5, -8, -8, -7, -8],
     [-4, -2, -4, -8, -9],
     [-4, -2, -5, -8, -7]]

import numpy as np

def procedure(matrix):
    return np.absolute(np.array(matrix))


procedure(a)
```

Comment: The OP said "no return value"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` if you really want to, but you have to cast to a list because it uses lazy evaluation. You must also deal with the inner lists (the rows). The result is not easy to read:

```
list(map(lambda row: list(map(abs, row)), matrix))
```

This is cute, but I think most Python programmers would use list comprehensions (or NumPy).

Comment: The OP said "no return value"

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica This isn't a function, the OP can do whatever they like with it, including wrapping it in a function that mutates some global. (I think that's a rotten idea, so I didn't do it.)